# MySQL Startup Error - Root element missing

Tags: windows, mysql, windows-server-2003

I have had MySQL installed for about 2 months on Windows Server 2003 R2. On start up we get presented with an error that says "High Severity Error - root element missing" followed by another high severity error that displays "Log file path must be defined before calling the WriteToLog method".

Any help with this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 21):

This might be a problem with MySQL notifier config file. As described [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?173,575890,581846#msg-581846), there is something wrong with your config file. You just have to remove it (or rename it to something else) and launch the MySQL notifier again - config file will be recreated automatically.

In my case, the config file was in the `C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\Oracle\MySQL Notifier\settings.config` path. Removing it solved the problem.

Comment: worked for me ty :)

Comment: mine is solved in windows 10 by renaming/deleteting those two files... connections.xml and  C:\Users\saber\AppData\Roaming\Oracle\MySQL Notifier\settings.config then after signout or restart mysql in startup regenerate connections.xml again. by openning mysql workbench you can regenerate connections.xml

Comment: This happened to me in 2024. settings.config contained a couple hundred NUL characters. Deleting the file solved the problem.

Answer (score 9):

I, too, ran across this problem on my local install of MySQL Notifier, and neither deleting settings.config, nor reinstalling had any effect. Further investigation lead me to a file in the same folder with the name connections.xml that only contained a single space character. Deleting that file and restarting the notifier did the trick, though, so if (like me) deleting settings.config doesn't correct the problem, look for connections.xml, and inspect that file for possible problems, deleting when necessary.

Comment: I had the same problem and deleting these two files was the solution. thanks Dave.

Comment: I had the same problem on Windows 8. Deleting connections.xml and settings.config fixed the problem. The both files can be found in C:\Users\User\AppData\..

Answer (score 3):

The error appears due to a corrupted configuration file and the solution is to delete it as mentioned by Wojciech Frącz.

It can also appear due to dummy MySQL services (Leftovers from server installations not completely removed). Always **make sure** you're **running** the **latest Notifier** version available (that can be downloaded at [mysql downloads page](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/installer/)) first.

**To solve the dummy MySQL services leftovers:**

3. Open a Run command window and type the following:

   > `services.msc`
4. Take note of any MySQL service that shouldn't be listed (attempted uninstall before).
5. Open an Admin rights command window and type the command:

   > sc delete "< Dummy_service_name_here >".

Restart Notifier and see if that corrected the problem.

If a similar error still appears afterwards, check if the stack trace shows the word CreateScheduledTask somewhere, that would mean something is wrong when Notifier tries to add a schedule task at startup to check for updates of any installed MySQL product.

A workaround is to open in notepad the `settings.config` file that was re-generated. Inside the file, look for a property called `"AutoCheckForUpdates"` and change the default value of `"True"` for `"False"` and run Notifier again, as noted in [this post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?173,605658,605696#msg-605696).

Answer (score 0):

I had a defective setting.config **and** a superfluous connections.xml. When I renamed both, mysql restarted. I then set connections.xml back to its original name. This blocked starting again, so I removed it altogether and mysql is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I solved deleting `C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\Oracle\MySQL Notifier\settings.config`
It was full of zeros ("null" bytes).

Note that MySQL Notifier may be still running in background (but non working fine), so you should kill it befor then restart the app.